# Send Geometry to query using ArcGIS REST API

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, json, visual-studio

I am writing a windows console app in VS 2010 to perform an overlay using the ArcGIS Rest API.

My first REST query returns information about the geometry for a specific feature.  I then want to send that geometry to another feature class, to return data about the shared area.

I am using the DeserializeObject method to convert the query results to a Dictionary.  How do I take the geometry from that result set and post it to a new query?

**Update:**

What if I user the JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize method on the geometry string?  Is there a way to pass the resulting JSON string to the REST service call?  I already tried just assigning it to the "geometry" value in the querystring, but that failed.

Comment: "send that to another feature class" ... is that local or through another REST call?

Comment: Another REST call

Comment: Would dependencies on Esri's [WPF SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#SpatialQuery) assemblies be acceptable?

Comment: I've considered that, I wanted to see if there was a way to do it just with REST calls before I opted for that route.

Comment: Have you tried Vish's [GeoJson.NET](http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2008/05/11/geojsonnet-a-net-library-to-produce-geojson-output/) ?

Comment: If you have the geometry string, did you try just using it to build a [url for a query](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/1/query?geometry=-125.4,35.2,-118.7,43.8&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&f=pjson)?

Comment: @Kirk, I used JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize to convert the Geometry object (A collection of points) into a string.  I tried plugging that into the query string, but the query failed.

Comment: Go ahead and post the query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below works for me.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string baseUrl = @"http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer";
                string jsonGeom = GetStateGeom(baseUrl,1, "Colorado");
                string featuresJson = QueryHighways(baseUrl, 0, jsonGeom);
                Console.WriteLine(featuresJson);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string GetStateGeom(string baseUrl, int layerID,string state)
        {
            string url = String.Format("{0}/{1}/query?text={2}&f=pjson",baseUrl,layerID,state);

            var wc = new WebClient();
            var strm =  wc.OpenRead(new Uri(url));
            var strmReader = new StreamReader(strm);
            var json = strmReader.ReadToEnd();
            //Console.WriteLine(json);
            strm.Close();
            var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
            JArray features = (JArray)jObj["features"];
            if (features.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("state of {0} not found", state);
                return null;
            }
            string jsonGeom = ((JObject)features[0])["geometry"].ToString();
            return jsonGeom;
        }

        private static string QueryHighways(string baseUrl, int layerID,string jsonGeom)
        {
            string url = String.Format("{0}/{1}/query", baseUrl, layerID);
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon");
            sb.Append(String.Format("&geometry={0}",jsonGeom));
            sb.Append("&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects");
            sb.Append("&returnGeometry=true");
            sb.Append("&relationParam=");
            sb.Append("&where=");
            sb.Append("&returnCountOnly=false");
            sb.Append("&maxAllowableOffset=");
            sb.Append("&f=pjson");
            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
            var respBytes = wc.UploadData(url, "POST", bytes);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(respBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some JSON helpers i ArcObjects that you might be able to use, but I'm not sure if they are supported on the client side though: 
[SOESupport.JsonObject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_JSON_in_a_REST_server_object_extension/000100000nw6000000/)